# Python - Adding all digits in string

Tags: python

How can i create a function that returns the sum of a string made up of 3 or more digits. For example, if the parameter/string is "13456". How can I return the result of (1*3 + 3*4 + 4*5 + 5*6). Thank you, all help is appreciated. Very new to python.

Answer (score 1):

Another one-liner:

```
a = '13456'

print(sum([int(x)*int(y) for x, y in zip(a[1:], a[:-1])]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_string = "12345"
total = 0
for n in range(len(my_string) - 1):
    total += int(my_string[n]) * int(my_string[n+1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to go through the string, multiplying the actual value to the next value and add it to a variable to return it later.

```
def func(param):
    ret = 0
    for i in range(len(param)-1):
        ret = ret + int(param[i]) * int(param[i+1])
    return ret
```

Answer (score 0):

This function first turns your string into a list and then applies a map on it to convert all the elements to ints. Finally it uses a loop to access and multiply consecutive elements,

```
def str_sum(nstr):
    nint = list(map(int, list(nstr)));
    res = 0;
    for i in range(len(nint[:-1])):
        res += nint[i]*nint[i+1]
    return res
```

Converting result of `map` into list using `list(map(...))` is redundant in Python 2.7 but necessary in Python 3.X as map returns an object instead of a list.

Answer (score 0):

Use `range` + `sum`

```
l = '13456'
sum([int(l[i])*int(l[i+1]) for i in range(len(l)-1)])
#Output:
#65
```

with `range(len(l)-1)`, you can get the start, end indexes like below

```
Output:[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Looping through the above list and indexing on list l,

```
int(l[i])*int(l[i+1]) # gives [1*3, 3*4 , ...]
```

Summing the output list

```
sum([1*3, 3*4 , ...]) # gives 65
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(input):
    return sum([int(input[i])*int(input[i+1]) for i in range(len(input)-1)])
```